# Are there examples of running Jetty 9.4 with JSP support or Pax Web with JSP support in a plain Equinox framework?

Tags: java, jetty, osgi, pax-web

I am attempting to get Jetty 9.4 with JSP support running in our applications OSGI container. I've used the information at
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/framework-jetty-osgi.html
to get jetty running and serving static pages. WHen I try accessing a JSP I get
"java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JettyJasperInitializer not a subtype"
I"m looking for examples of running Jetty in a plain OSGI container to help me debug my configuration. I'd also be interested in examples of using Pax Web in an OSGI container. So far all the Pax Web doc I've found assumes your running in Karaf.

Comment: Are you using the required Spi-Fly?  If so, you'll need to stick with Java 8 (SpiFly not supported on newer JVMs)

Answer (score 1):

Jetty's own `jetty-osgi/test-jetty-osgi` uses [PAX Web to test it's own implementation](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-osgi/test-jetty-osgi/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/osgi/test/TestJettyOSGiBootWithJsp.java).

It's based on behaviors present in the [`jetty-osgi-boot-jsp`](http://See:%20https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-osgi/jetty-osgi-boot-jsp) project

Note: Apache Aries Spi-Fly is a mandatory requirement. Which unfortunately forces you to stick with Java 8 (as it doesn't support ASM 7 yet)